# Close modal panel after invoking h:commandButton submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, jsf-2

I am trying to download a large file with a `<h:commandButton>` and I want to warn users that the download operation would take a few seconds/minutes by showing them a 'wait' modal.

My problem is that I can show the image with the button's onclick event but I don't know how to hide it when the action is complete (this is when the dialog popup to download the file is shown).

My code is like:

```
<h:form id="form">

    <h:commandButton value="Download" 
        action="#{bean.downloadFile()}"
        onclick="showModal('waitModal')"/>

        <div id="waitModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1"
            role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        WAIT!
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  

</h:form>
```

A solution would be using a flag in the bean and call a javascript function with a timeout which checks the flag's value and close the modal when the download has finished but it is not what I'm looking for...it should be more generic because I have to apply it in several locations

I know there are a few similar questions but I didn't find any solution that I can apply to my problem.

Thanks at all!

Comment: Did you think about using PrimeFaces? They provide an example for your problem in their showcase: [p:fileDownload](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/download.xhtml).

Comment: I think about that option but adding a new framework only for this situation is not something we are considering at the moment. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

PrimeFaces solved your problem with [p:fileDownload](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/download.xhtml). If you don't want to use PrimeFaces you can at least have a look how they implemented it.

PrimeFaces sets a cookie to the response which indicates that download is completed. At the client side they use a [window interval function](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) which is registered when the download button is clicked. This function checks the mentioned cookie at a specific interval. If the cookie is set it will be resetted, the interval function will be unregistered and a callback function will be called that you could use to close your dialog.

For implementation details have a look at monitorDownload method in PrimeFaces' [core.js](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/core/core.js) and the implementation of [p:fileDownload](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/tree/master/src/main/java/org/primefaces/component/filedownload).

I think it's easy to implement and you can reuse it very well. I don't think there is another better solution, because a file download requires a full page request (not an ajax request), so you can't register a callback function or something like that.